# Google Map to go to precise location without zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

I have made a google map in which i have entered latitude and longitude of customer after running the app it shows the map of India, I have to zoom 2 to 3 times to get that perfect location.How will i do this without zooming it,it will get to that perfect location

Answer (score 0):

You can set zoom level as per your wish at specific latlong location using

**mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(getlatitude(), getlongitude),zoom)**

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods through which can you zoom into a particular location.

> With Animation

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoomLevel));
```

> Without Animation

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
```